# Call a lightning aura component from a button from a Tab?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, tab, quickaction

I have a Lightning Aura Component NewRecord and it's just a modal with some basic form fields.

I have an object called MyObject__c with a Tab. From the Tab I want to call the lightning aura component NewRecord? Is that possible? It appears I can only create a Custom Button List and then hard code the URL, but it doesn't give the "modal" experience.

[image]

The button will just call a lightning aura component where it's a dialog modal like below.

[image]

When I tried to override the Edit and New buttons with the aura component, what is happening is the modal opens up, but the background disappears.

[image]

Comment: Didn't understand `From the Tab I want to call the lightning component?`

Comment: @NagendraSingh  I added some screenshot. Basically, I want a custom button in my Tab that calls a lightning component. My main problem is that I tried to override the Edit and New with this aura component, but when clicking the New or Edit button, the Modal shows up but the "background" totally disappears.

Comment: I tried this and it will work for me 

lightning/o/{objectApiName}/new?navigationLocation=LIST_VIEW&backgroundContext=/lightning/o/{objectApiName}/list?filterName=Recent